How to check canceled events in firebase web
How to determine or track if an event was sent successfully and is not in a "canceled" state?
Events are not being delivered, and I don’t know how to implement retries.
To enable retries, I at least need to track if the event was sent.
The logEvent function returns void in the Firebase JS SDK.
import {
    logEvent,
} from 'firebase/analytics';

//other code

    public logEvent(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
        const dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        const name = toSnakeCase(dataCopy.name as string);

        if (this.isSkipLog) return;

        logEvent(this.analytics, name, {
            context_platform: 'web',
        });
    }

I tried to find a solution in the library, wrapping it in a try-catch block, but I couldn’t find a solution anywhere.
